# Remove space before cells in Grouped uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, grouped-table

I am having UITableView which i selected tableview style as "Grouped".

But I am having problem here that it is showing some empty space on the top of table view and at the end of the tableview. For this i used the below code:

```
[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 30)];
```

but when I scrolled down it is showing that empty space.

Can anybody tell me how to remove this white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding height of table sections headers

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 1.0f; 
}
```

And tableview footer view

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:view];
```